# unable to install docker using snap; cannot run install hook of "docker" snap

Tags: docker, snap

I was attempting to install docker with snap and the error message is as follows:

```
l@l-Lenovo-Rescuer-15ISK:~$ sudo snap install docker
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Run install hook of "docker" snap if present (run hook "install": 
-----
cannot update snap namespace: cannot create symlink in "/etc/docker": existing file in the way
snap-update-ns failed with code 1
-----)
```

Answer (score 8):

**simply fix the problem by running the commands below**

1. `sudo rm -rf /etc/docker`
2. `sudo snap refresh`